# Accessing Laravel on LAN

Tags: laravel, nginx, debian, localhost

I am trying to access laravel using lan and ip of server which is LEMP. Whereas the sites open correctly but after I try to open other pages the laravel gives me a "You are forbidden to perform this action." error.

Why is laravel it self blocking my access and how we can allow it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

made a .htaccess file in the app's root folder (the public_html folder) with this contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

I think it will solve your problem